# How can I get a certificate by name given in ServiceDefinition on Azure

Tags: azure

```
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="MyRandomName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
</Certificates>
```

When I have above in my ServiceDefinition.csdef. Is this the name 'MyRandomName' that the certificate gets on the server?

How do it get a X509Certificate2 instance of it in the OnStart call ? Is it needed that I have a setting also telling the thumbprint to look it up by?

Comment: Declaring the certificate info in ServiceDef&Config files allows you to access the certificate installed in the local machine. You should make appropriate entry in your web.config & app.config to access it by thumbprint

Comment: My goal here is not to had entries twice. The user already adds  <Certificate name="MyRandomName thumbprint="3D3275357F9DADDDF31F7597656B42137BBBCD56" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" /> in cscfg - so there must be someway I can get this certificate from code without the user having to put it in app.config also. (its a role deployment. the user just edits the cscfg and deploy the package).

Comment: I agree with @pksorensen, there is no point to duplicate information. I'd really want to access the certificate by name or at least access certificate thumbprint by name to get the certificate later on. The question is really good, however I don't like the answer, should be something more elegant :(

Comment: I am using the Azure Keyvault at this point to store certificates as secret instead. Works nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution to my problem:

I can decrypt a setting like this:

```
  var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(setting);
  var envelope = new EnvelopedCms();
  envelope.Decode(encryptedBytes);
  var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
  store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
  envelope.Decrypt(store.Certificates);
  string passwordChars = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(envelope.ContentInfo.Content);
```

when it has been encryptet like this:

```
        X509Certificate2 cert = LoadCertificate(
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My,
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.CurrentUser, args[0]);

        byte[] encoded = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(args[1]);
        var content = new ContentInfo(encoded);
        var env = new EnvelopedCms(content);
        env.Encrypt(new CmsRecipient(cert));

        string encrypted64 = Convert.ToBase64String(env.Encode());
```

This means the user do not have to add any thumbprints other than the

```
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="Composite.WindowsAzure.Management" thumbprint="3D3275357F9DADDDF31F7597656B42137BBBCD56" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
</Certificates>
```

in cscfg for their Cloud Service, and also upload it on the portal ofcause.

The args[0] and args[1] are just a thumbprint of the certificate to use and settingvalue to encrypt.