# Azure WorkerRole: Certificate Key not valid for use in specified state

Tags: azure

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Key not valid for
>   use in specified state.
>
> at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr)    at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._ExportKey(SafeKeyHandle
>   hKey, Int32 blobType, Object cspObject)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(Boolean
>   includePrivateParameters)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.ToXmlString(Boolean
>   includePrivateParameters)

Now, i belive this happens because that when Azure adds the Certificate to my WorkerRole deployment, it do not install the certificate with the option "Mark this Key as Exportable".

I need to add a certificate to my workerrole to beable to decypt a encryptet setting.

Anyone have any ideas about how i can make Azure Mark the certificates private key as exportable. or if it could be another issue.

Onstart:

```
    try{

        var conn = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(setting), true, cert));

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());

    }
```

Methods:

```
        public static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate(StoreName storeName,
   StoreLocation storeLocation, string tprint)
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);

            try
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

                X509Certificate2Collection certificateCollection =
                     store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                            tprint, false);

                if (certificateCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    //  We ignore if there is more than one matching cert, 
                    //  we just return the first one.
                    return certificateCollection[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Certificate not found");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                store.Close();
            }
        }
    public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedData, bool fOAEP,
                           X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        if (encryptedData == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("encryptedData");
        }
        if (certificate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");
        }

        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            // Note that we use the private key to decrypt
            provider.FromXmlString(GetXmlKeyPair(certificate));

            return provider.Decrypt(encryptedData, fOAEP);
        }
    }
    public static string GetXmlKeyPair(X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        if (certificate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");
        }

        if (!certificate.HasPrivateKey)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("certificate does not have a private key");
        }
        else
        {
            return certificate.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

the answer is given in another question of mine here: [How can I get a certificate by name given in ServiceDefinition on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652778/how-can-i-get-a-certificate-by-name-given-in-servicedefinition-on-azure/18674814#18674814)